# for performace, static class or regular object creation

Tags: java, android

Currently making a simple Android SurfaceView base game. There are a lot of calls like this:

```
mSplatGraphic[idx] = new Random().nextInt(SPLAT_COUNT);
```

My question is, would it be better performance wise to have a "static random class" like this:

```
public class SysRandom {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static int nextInt(int limit) {
         return RANDOM.nextInt(limit);
    }
}
```

And use this code instead:

```
mSplatGraphic[idx] = SysRandom.nextInt(SPLAT_COUNT);
```

My thinking is, with the simple class, the Random object is created once and is not being constantly created and destroyed, however I'm not sure that is what is really happening once the code is compiled and running.

This may be a java noob question, sorry! I'm self-taught and happy to remove the question if someone just points me to a link :]

Comment: instead of creating a new Random each time, why not have a class field?

Comment: @panini Ahh, yes. That would work and be even better than creating class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would not use either of the options you suggested.  First of all, there is no need to create a new Random every time you need a random number.  This will cause a significant amount of unnecessary garbage collection, which can negatively impact fps.  Using your SysRandom wrapper should help, but I do not think wrapping it in that utility class is necessary.  Personally, I would declare a

`private final Random rand = new Random()`

at the top of your class that uses `mSplatGraphic`.  Unless you access `rand` statically, I would not make it static.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be faster, especially if this code is placed in a loop because the object would be created, and then the garbage collector would have to collect it instantly. Placing it in its own class would increase performance, though not by a huge amount. The Android documentation [has a page](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation) very appropriate to this situation.